# Finding limits in two variables with trig functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus

How do I find the limit as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ for $\frac{\cos(x)+\cos(y)-2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and $\frac{\sin(x+2y)-x-2y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Comment: I tried looking at when x=0 and y is not equal to zero, when y=0 and x is not equal to zero, and when x=y.  I think that's generally the procedure, but I'm not exactly sure where I'm supposed to go from there.

Comment: Are you sure that in the first limit there is a minus sign between the two cos functions? If yes, the first limit is $-\infty$ by just plugging in the values.

Comment: It was supposed to be a plus sign, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

We have:$$\cos x+\cos y-2=-4(\sin^2 {x\over 2}+\sin^2 {y\over 2})\sim -2x^2-2y^2$$therefore the first limit becomes zero as well as the 2nd one which becomes zero either using Taylor series of $\sin u$ in $u=0$.